# How to wait for completion of multiple tasks in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What is the proper way to implement concurrency in Java applications? I know about Threads and stuff, of course, I have been programming for Java for 10 years now, but haven't had too much experience with concurrency.

For example, I have to asynchronously load a few resources, and only after all have been loaded, can I proceed and do more work. Needless to say, there is no order how they will finish. How do I do this?

In JavaScript, I like using the `jQuery.deferred` infrastructure, to say

```
$.when(deferred1,deferred2,deferred3...)
 .done(
   function(){//here everything is done
    ...
   });
```

But what do I do in Java?

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: Take a look at RxJava

Comment: Look up Java Threads on google. Quite easy to implement concurrency in Java.

Comment: @FelipeSulser Quite easy to do it wrong, as often evidenced by the questions on SO.

Comment: CountdownLatch or CyclicBarrier can help

Comment: Android Java, Java 7. I know about Threads, as I said, I've been dealing with java for 10 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not using parallel Streams or Spring MVC's TaskExecutor, I usually use `CountDownLatch`. Instantiate with # of tasks, reduce once for each thread that completes its task. `CountDownLatch.await()` waits until the latch is at 0. Really useful.

Read more here: [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: @doom777 CountdownLatch is used to start a series of threads and then wait until all of them are complete (or until they call countDown() a given number of times).

Semaphore is used to control the number of concurrent threads that are using a resource. That resource can be something like a file, or could be the cpu by limiting the number of threads executing. The count on a Semaphore can go up and down as different threads call acquire() and release().

Comment: It has more usage than that. It can basically function as a simple executor-pool. Using it for the sole purpose of counting in "one direction" (be it up _or_ down) seems a bit pointless to me.

Answer (score 9):

I would use parallel stream.

```
Stream.of(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3).parallel().forEach(r -> r.run());
// do something after all these are done.
```

If you need this to be asynchronous, then you might use a pool or Thread.

> I have to asynchronously load a few resources,

You could collect these resources like this.

```
List<String> urls = ....

Map<String, String> map = urls.parallelStream()
                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(u -> u, u -> download(u)));
```

This will give you a mapping of all the resources once they have been downloaded concurrently. The concurrency will be the number of CPUs you have by default.

Comment: @RobinJonsson forEach doesn't return until all the tasks have completed. There is no support for running stream code asynchronously which is why you would need to do something else if you need this.

Comment: You don't always have runnable, and you don't always have control over async.

For example, I am calling an external method called `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback).` which returns immediately, and starts it's own thread. There are other things I need to load in a similar manner, and perform code after everything is done. I think the best solution I found is the `CountDownLatch` is the correct solution here.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve it in multiple ways.

1.[ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) `invokeAll()` API

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete.

2.[CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.
>
> A `CountDownLatch` is initialized with a given count. The await methods block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the `countDown()` method, after which all waiting threads are released and any subsequent invocations of await return immediately. This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.

3.[ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) or  `newWorkStealingPool()` in [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) is other way

Have a look at related SE questions:

[How to wait for a thread that spawns it's own thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075886/how-to-wait-for-a-thread-that-spawns-its-own-thread/35076391#35076391)

[Executors: How to synchronously wait until all tasks have finished if tasks are created recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535770/executors-how-to-synchronously-wait-until-all-tasks-have-finished-if-tasks-are)

Comment: Great answer. I'd also add CyclicBarrier — it has a constructor, which accepts a Runnable, that will be executed when all tasks are finished: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier-int-java.lang.Runnable-

Comment: Which is the correct way to do the same thing, but without blocking any threads?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would do something like this if I am using Java 8 or later.

```
// Retrieving instagram followers
CompletableFuture<Integer> instagramFollowers = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // getInstaFollowers(userId);

    return 0; // default value
});

// Retrieving twitter followers
CompletableFuture<Integer> twitterFollowers = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // getTwFollowers(userId);

    return 0; // default value
});

System.out.println("Calculating Total Followers...");
CompletableFuture<Integer> totalFollowers = instagramFollowers
    .thenCombine(twitterFollowers, (instaFollowers, twFollowers) -> {
         return instaFollowers + twFollowers; // can be replaced with method reference
});

System.out.println("Total followers: " + totalFollowers.get()); // blocks until both the above tasks are complete
```

I used `supplyAsync()` as I am returning some value (no. of followers in this case) from the tasks otherwise I could have used `runAsync()`. Both of these run the task in a separate thread.

Finally, I used `thenCombine()` to join both the `CompletableFuture`. You could also use `thenCompose()` to join two `CompletableFuture` if one depends on the other. But in this case, as both the tasks can be executed in parallel, I used `thenCombine()`.

The methods `getInstaFollowers(userId)` and `getTwFollowers(userId)` are simple HTTP calls or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ThreadPool and Executors to do this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an example I use Threads. Its a static executerService with a fixed size of 50 threads.

```
public class ThreadPoolExecutor {

private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50,
        new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("thread-%d").build());

private static ThreadPoolExecutor instance = new ThreadPoolExecutor();

public static ThreadPoolExecutor getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public <T> Future<? extends T> queueJob(Callable<? extends T> task) {
    return executorService.submit(task);
}

public void shutdown() {
    executorService.shutdown();
}
}
```

The business logic for the executer is used like this: (You can use Callable or Runnable. Callable can return something, Runnable not)

```
public class MultipleExecutor implements Callable<ReturnType> {//your code}
```

And the call of the executer:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = ThreadPoolExecutor.getInstance();

List<Future<? extends ReturnType>> results = new LinkedList<>();

for (Type Type : typeList) {
            Future<? extends ReturnType> future = threadPoolExecutor.queueJob(
                    new MultipleExecutor(needed parameters));
            results.add(future);
        }

        for (Future<? extends ReturnType> result : results) {
            try {
                if (result.get() != null) {
                    result.get(); // here you get the return of one thread
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                logger.error(e, e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The same behaviour as with `$.Deferred` in `jQuery` you can archive in `Java 8` with a class called `CompletableFuture`. This class provides the API for working with `Promises`. In order to create async code you can use one of it's `static` creational methods like `#runAsync`, `#supplyAsync`. Then applying some computation of results with `#thenApply`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually opt for an async notify-start, notify-progress, notify-end approach:

```
class Task extends Thread {
    private ThreadLauncher parent;

    public Task(ThreadLauncher parent) {
        super();
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void run() {
        doStuff();

        parent.notifyEnd(this);
    }

    public /*abstract*/ void doStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}


class ThreadLauncher {

    public void stuff() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            new Task(this).start(); 
    }

    public void notifyEnd(Task who) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, you can implement Runnable if you wish to do so